# Using MixedReality-WebRTC Screen Capture

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm making a UWP app using MixedReality-WebRTC.

Is there a way to get the current screen real-time, not a webcam?

Comment: Hey, did you find out how to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the current screen real-time

Sure, you could use `GraphicsCapturePicker` to pick window that you want to capture, and use screen capture api the get real time frame with `FrameArrived` event.

```
_framePool.FrameArrived += (s, a) =>
{
    // The FrameArrived event fires for every frame on the thread that
    // created the Direct3D11CaptureFramePool. This means we don't have to
    // do a null-check here, as we know we're the only one  
    // dequeueing frames in our application.  

    // NOTE: Disposing the frame retires it and returns  
    // the buffer to the pool.
    using (var frame = _framePool.TryGetNextFrame())
    {
        // We'll define this method later in the document.
        ProcessFrame(frame);
    }  
};
```

And here is [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture-video) that you could refer.

Comment: Thank you. I am having various difficulties as I am working on a WebRTC project through UWP for the first time.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use microsoft / Mixed Reality-WebRTC to deliver the UWP screen instead of a webcam?

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT I tried what you said and I'm stuck at point that now I have a Direct3D11CaptureFrame, but MR-WebRTC needs a frame in [YUV420](https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV/#I420). Do you know how to convert that?

Comment: @Nico Zhu - MSFT I created also a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66800357/mixed-reality-webrtc-screen-capturing-with-graphicscapturepicker?noredirect=1&lq=1) here on so for this.