# Mixed Reality WebRTC - Screen capturing with GraphicsCapturePicker

Tags: c#, uwp, webrtc, directx-11, hololens

**Setup**
Hey,
I'm trying to capture my screen and send/communicate the stream via [MR-WebRTC](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/index.html). Communication between two PCs or PC with HoloLens worked with webcams for me, so I thought the next step could be streaming my screen. So I took the uwp application that I already had, which worked with my webcam and tried to make things work:

- UWP App is based on [the example uwp app](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/cs/helloworld-cs-uwp.html) from MR-WebRTC.
- For Capturing I'm using the [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) from MS about screen capturing via GraphicsCapturePicker.

**So now I'm stuck in the following situation:**

1. I get a frame from the screen capturing, but its type is [Direct3D11CaptureFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.direct3d11captureframe?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(Windows.Graphics.Capture.Direct3D11CaptureFrame);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%253Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=winrt-19041). You can see it below in the code snipped.
2. MR-WebRTC takes a frame type `I420AVideoFrame` (also in a code snipped).

**How can I "connect" them?**

- `I420AVideoFrame` wants a frame in the I420A format (YUV 4:2:0).
- Configuring the framePool I can set the [DirectXPixelFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/uwp/api/windows.graphics.directx.directxpixelformat?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(Windows.Graphics.DirectX.DirectXPixelFormat);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%253Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=winrt-19041), but it has no YUV420.
- I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65389900/using-mixedreality-webrtc-screen-capture) on so, saying that it its possible.

**Code Snipped Frame from Direct3D:**

```
_framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.Create(
                _canvasDevice,                             // D3D device
                DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, // Pixel format
                3,                                         // Number of frames
                _item.Size);                               // Size of the buffers

_session = _framePool.CreateCaptureSession(_item);
_session.StartCapture();
_framePool.FrameArrived += (s, a) =>
{
    using (var frame = _framePool.TryGetNextFrame())
    {
        // Here I would take the Frame and call the MR-WebRTC method LocalI420AFrameReady  
    }
};
```

**Code Snippet Frame from WebRTC:**

```
// This is the way with the webcam; so LocalI420 was subscribed to
// the event I420AVideoFrameReady and got the frame from there
_webcamSource = await DeviceVideoTrackSource.CreateAsync();
_webcamSource.I420AVideoFrameReady += LocalI420AFrameReady;

// enqueueing the newly captured video frames into the bridge,
// which will later deliver them when the Media Foundation
// playback pipeline requests them.
private void LocalI420AFrameReady(I420AVideoFrame frame)
    {
        lock (_localVideoLock)
        {
            if (!_localVideoPlaying)
            {
                _localVideoPlaying = true;

                // Capture the resolution into local variable useable from the lambda below
                uint width = frame.width;
                uint height = frame.height;

                // Defer UI-related work to the main UI thread
                RunOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    // Bridge the local video track with the local media player UI
                    int framerate = 30; // assumed, for lack of an actual value
                    _localVideoSource = CreateI420VideoStreamSource(
                        width, height, framerate);
                    var localVideoPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    localVideoPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(
                        _localVideoSource);
                    localVideoPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(localVideoPlayer);
                    localVideoPlayer.Play();
                });
            }
        }
        // Enqueue the incoming frame into the video bridge; the media player will
        // later dequeue it as soon as it's ready.
        _localVideoBridge.HandleIncomingVideoFrame(frame);
    }
```

Comment: NV12 is probably the closest to I420. There is an example here of converting the other way around (I420 => NV12)= https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/blob/a721bdf311ecebbea757eb80222e08e7949a8d58/examples/TestAppUwp/Video/YuvUtils.cs#L157

Comment: thanks for replying. I'm gonna check this tomorrow out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem by creating an issue on the github repo. [Answer](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/issues/721#issuecomment-810709138) was provided by [KarthikRichie](https://github.com/KarthikRichie):

1. You have to use the `ExternalVideoTrackSource`
2. You can convert from the `Direct3D11CaptureFrame` to `Argb32VideoFrame`

```
// Setting up external video track source
_screenshareSource = ExternalVideoTrackSource.CreateFromArgb32Callback(FrameCallback);

struct WebRTCFrameData
{
    public IntPtr Data;
    public uint Height;
    public uint Width;
    public int Stride;
}

public void FrameCallback(in FrameRequest frameRequest)
{
    try
    {
        if (FramePool != null)
        {
            using (Direct3D11CaptureFrame _currentFrame = FramePool.TryGetNextFrame())
            {
                if (_currentFrame != null)
                {
                    WebRTCFrameData webRTCFrameData = ProcessBitmap(_currentFrame.Surface).Result;
                    frameRequest.CompleteRequest(new Argb32VideoFrame()
                    {
                        data = webRTCFrameData.Data,
                        height = webRTCFrameData.Height,
                        width = webRTCFrameData.Width,
                        stride = webRTCFrameData.Stride
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private async Task<WebRTCFrameData> ProcessBitmap(IDirect3DSurface surface)
{

    SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromSurfaceAsync(surface, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.Straight);

    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[4 * softwareBitmap.PixelWidth * softwareBitmap.PixelHeight];
    softwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer(imageBytes.AsBuffer());
    WebRTCFrameData argb32VideoFrame = new WebRTCFrameData();
    argb32VideoFrame.Data = GetByteIntPtr(imageBytes);
    argb32VideoFrame.Height = (uint)softwareBitmap.PixelHeight;
    argb32VideoFrame.Width = (uint)softwareBitmap.PixelWidth;

    var test = softwareBitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.Read);
    int count = test.GetPlaneCount();
    var pl = test.GetPlaneDescription(count - 1);
    argb32VideoFrame.Stride = pl.Stride;

    return argb32VideoFrame;

}

private IntPtr GetByteIntPtr(byte[] byteArr)
{
    IntPtr intPtr2 = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(byteArr, 0);
    return intPtr2;
}
```